# 64 bit alternative shell

Tags: windows, 64-bit, shell

Im looking for a **64 bit**, minimalistic replacement shell for Windows XP/Vista/7. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Emerge Desktop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emerge/files/) is available as 64bit.

[LiteStep](http://www.litestep.net/) is only 32bit, as far as I see it.

[GeoShell](http://www.geoshell.com/) is also only 32bit.

All found via a quick google. Sorry, but you really need to google your things first, instead of making the community here do the work for you.

Comment: Emerge looks *terrible*.

Answer (score 2):

Gotta love the Jackboots and the way they always tell you to use Google, eh? Yeah, I been browsing for alt shells too. Just installed Talisman on Windows 7 64 bit, and it seems to work like it's supposed to. BUt I uninstalled it because it doesn't live up to my expectations. Litestep community is currently working on getting their shell compatible with 7, but no clue about 64 bit  atm. I run Litestep on my XP 32 bit machine, and it is not only the shell I prefer, but also the one I would suggest using. There are a few other shells out there, but none that really catch my eye as far as usability, or cosmetic beauty. If you would just like to make your windows look better, I was running Windowblinds on my Vista 64 bit OS until I replaced the system with 7. Currently their is no compatible version of Windowblinds that operates with 7, however.